# How to migrate a Salesforce custom field using Mavensmate?

Tags: maven, salesforce, sublimetext3, migrate

I'm using Mavensmate and Sublime to migrate custom object fields from one Salesforce sandbox org to another. I have successfully exported the custom fields from the Origin Sandbox, and see the fields defined in the Sublime project under `src/objects`.

I've created another Mavensmate/Sublime project for the Target Sandbox, and have tried simply copying the `package.xml` file and the `src/objects` directory to the new project, but deploying the changes via Mavensmate to Salesforce has no effect, and I am unable to see the custom fields in the Mavensmate project for the Target org.

In Mavensmate, clicking on 'Update Project' from within the Edit Project dashboard removes my changes to `package.xml` and the copied `src/objects` directory, however 'Refresh Metadata Index' has no effect at all.

How do I migrate these fields to Sandbox Target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish the custom metadata migration successfully using the [Salesforce Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) with Java 1.8 & Ant 1.10.1

Answer (score 0):

To deploy to a remote environment using MavensMate:

1. Select the requisite metadata (in your case, custom fields) from your source environment: MavensMate > Edit Project
2. Set up a connection to your target environment: MavensMate > Deployment Connections
3. Deploy to the target environment: MavensMate > Deploy to Server

hth

Comment: Thanks @joseph-ferraro, I was able to push to the org, but am still lost on migrating the fields from one Sublime project (Origin) to the other (Target). I can copy the files fine, but then how do I let Mavesmate know that the project for the Target org's metadata has been changed?

Comment: @NathanBennett, you should refresh the metadata index for the Target org project and edit the project to include your new metadata.

Comment: Hi @joseph-ferraro - it's still not working as I would expect it to. If I create a new Mavensmate project with CustomMetadata and CustomObject metadata, select a single object (Account) and create the project. When I copy the `src/objects/Account.object` file with the custom fields from the other Project and hit 'Refresh Metadata Index' I don't see any of the custom fields from the `src/objects/Account.object` file.

Comment: My next thought was to simply add a deployment connection to the Target Org from the Origin project. I added the connection, have selected the custom object fields in the Metadata tab of the Deploy dashboard, and while it says it has deployed successfully, when I log in to the Target org, the objects do not have the custom fields.